# Digest Authentication for ROBOTFRAMEWORK

Tags: robotframework, digest, digest-authentication

below is the begining of a script for testing a rest interface on a device , this device has a https server with Digest Authentication.
This is where i am encountering a problem below I have it set up I do not get an error so i assume 
Set Digest Auth                      admin        secret    is valid

if it is what can I not authenticate:

```
#script
*** Settings ***
Resource        variablesreal.txt
Library         HttpLibrary.HTTP
Library         PycURLLibrary
Library         OperatingSystem
Test Setup      Create HTTP Context  ${HOST}    https


*** Variables ***
${HEADER1}  Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8


*** Test Cases ***
Set Digest Auth
    Log Variables
    Verbose
    Add Header  ${HEADER1}
    Add Header  version:1
    Next Request Should Not Succeed
    GET                                 https://${HOST}/views


    Set Digest Auth                      admin        secret
    GET                                 https://${HOST}/views
    Response Status Code Should Equal   200
    Response Body Should Contain        views
    Log Response Status
    Log Response














here is the out put from pybot hls.txt
==============================================================================
Hls                                                                           
==============================================================================
Set Digest Auth                                                       | FAIL |
Request should have succeeded, but was "401 Unauthorized".
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hls                                                                   | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================

Output:  /home/robm/code/BDD/pycurl/hl/output.xml
Log:     /home/robm/code/BDD/pycurl/hl/log.html
Report:  /home/robm/code/BDD/pycurl/hl/report.html
```

any ideas on Digest authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding this to RequestKeywords.py

```
def create_digest_session(self, alias, url, auth, headers={}, cookies=None, timeout=None, proxies=None, verify=False):

    """ Create Session: create a HTTP session to a server

    `url` Base url of the server

    `alias` Robot Framework alias to identify the session

    `headers` Dictionary of default headers

    `auth` List of username & password for HTTP Digest Auth

    `timeout` connection timeout

    `proxies` proxy server url

    `verify` set to True if Requests should verify the certificate
    """
    digest_auth = requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth(*auth) if auth else None
    return self._create_session_local(alias, url, headers, cookies, digest_auth, timeout, proxies, verify)
```